# design pattern for class with data attached

Tags: design-patterns, c++, object-oriented-design, inheritance

I have a class `Tiles` that looks something like this:

```
class Tiles {
 public:
  void AddTile(int x) { tiles_.push_back(x); }
  std::vector<int> tiles_;
}
```

Now I want to create a class `Tiles` with data, i.e.,

```
class TilesWithData : public Tiles {
 public:
  void AddTile(int x, double data) { 
    tiles_.push_back(x);
    data_.push_back(data);  
  }
  std::vector<double> data_;
}
```

In this scenario I want that if a `TilesWithData` is created, the `AddTile(int x)` deleted, so that only the version `AddTile(int x, double data)` is available. Is that possible? What is the best design pattern for this case? Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate your use-case? Generally speaking what you described sounds a bit as if your design violates the LSP (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), or at least the principle of least astonishment, but it's a bit hard to tell without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

What *behaviours* do these classes have? At the moment you'd do better with

```
using Tile = int;
using Tiles = std::vector<Tile>;

struct TileWithData { Tile tile; double data; };
using TilesWithData = std::vector<TileWithData>;
```

The simple answer to your question is [prefer composition over inheritance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 5):

`TilesWithData` is publicly derived from `Tiles`, hence it can be assigned to a (smart or dumb) pointer of type `Tiles` (my C++ is a bit rusted, but basically this should be sound)

```
Tiles *tiles = new TilesWithData();
```

Disallowing `tiles->AddTile(123)` would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), since a client that has a pointer to a `Tiles` instance (be it an actual `Tiles` or a `TilesWithData`) would not know not to call `AddTile`.

If there is a common functionality, you might introduce an abstract base class for both

```
class Tiles 
{
    public:
        virtual vector<int> GetTiles() = 0; 
}
```

from which you can derive `SimpleTiles`

```
class SimpleTiles : public Tiles 
{
    public:
        void AddTile(int x) { tiles_.push_back(x); }
        std::vector<int> GetTiles 
        {
            return tiles_;
        }
    private:
        std::vector<int> tiles_;
}
```

and `TilesWithData`

```
class TilesWithData : Tiles
{
    public:
        void AddTile(int x, double data) 
        { 
            tiles_.push_back(x); 
            data_.push_back(data);
        }

        std::vector<int> GetTiles 
        {
            return tiles_;
        }

        std::vector<double> GetData()
        {
            return data_;
        }
    private:
        // elided
}
```

This way, the data (internals) of your class is encapsulated and you are free to change the actual internal implementation without breaking the clients of your code. Furthermore, any client, holding a reference to `Tiles` can be sure about its capabilities: Getting the list of tiles. Anything further is up to the derivatives.

**Remarks:** There is still plenty of space for improvements. The `Tiles` implementations are neither fish nor meat, they don't provide real logic, but they are neither simple collections. A better way could be abstrac tiles

```
class Tile
{
    public:
        virtual void Update() = 0;
}
```

and a single collection to hold all types derived from `Tile`

```
class Tiles
{
    public:
        void AddTile(std::shared_ptr<Tile> tileToAdd)
        {
            tiles_.push_back(tileToAdd);
        }

        void UpdateTiles()
        {
            for(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>>:iterator it = tiles_.begin(); it != tiles_.end(); it++)
            {
                (*it)->Update();
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>> tiles_;
}
```

Now you can implement different types of tiles suited to your needs

```
class SimpleTile : public Tile
{
    public:
        SimpleTile(int whatever)
        {
            // ...
        }

        void Update()
        {
            // ...
        }
    // ...
}

class TileWithData : public Tile 
{
    public:
        TileWithData(int whatever, double data)
        {
            // ...
            data_ = data;
        }

        void Update()
        {
            // ...
        }
    // ...
}
```

**Disclaimer:** It might well be that there are some errors in my C++ syntax. If my intention is clear, feel free to edit, otherwith, please leave me a comment.

Comment: Great answer! And there's no need to apologize for syntax details. This site is intended for [whiteboard-level questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/17/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/), and as discussed elsewhere [we cannot expect anyone to scribble perfect code on a whiteboard](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/106576) – a whiteboard doesn't have a compiler. Feel free to use any pseudocode you like, as long as it communicates your intent :)

Answer (score 2):

### The Template way of life

The only thing in common between `Tiles` and `TilesWithData` seem to be that they do similar things but with different data type.  So inheritance is not well suited. You should prefer a generic `Tiles` instead:

```
template <class DataType>
class Tiles {
 public:
  void AddTile(DataType x) { tiles_.push_back(x); }
  std::vector<DataType> tiles_;
};
```

Once this is defined, you can use any kind of tiles:

```
Tiles<int> a; 
a.AddTile(10); 

Tiles<std::string> b; 
b.AddTile("hello, world"); 

Tiles<std::tuple<int, double>> c; 
c.AddTile(std::make_tuple(20, 12.5));
```

Note the last example:  you could use your own type.  But if you just want to freely use a combination of several types without bothering, you can use [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/OSyQVx)

---

### In case you'd prefer to keep inheritance...

#### Design issues

There are several problems with your design:

- first, the data members should be `private` or `protected`.  What's the sense of worrying about the illegitimate use of `AddTile()`, if on the other hand, anybody could alter `tiles_` directly with a `push_back()` ?
- second, `TilesWithData::AddTile()` should not mess with `tiles_` directly, but rather use the base class interface (i.e. replace the explicit pushback with `Tiles::AddTile(x);`).  Why ?  Just imagine what would happen if you'd decide to switch to `std::list tiles_;` ...
- third, you use inheritance improperly:  if `TilesWithData` has a different interface, it is not really a kind of `Tiles` (and back to my first proposal ;-)

#### And it already works as you want !

With your classes, your scenario works already as desired ! This is  because of the name hiding.  For example, the following code will result in an error message:

```
TilesWithData b; 
b.AddTile(30);   /// OUCH !
```

The error message is:

```
prog.cpp:26:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘TilesWithData::AddTile(int)’
  b.AddTile(30);
              ^
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/L1FuOE)

If you wanted to use the base classe's `AddTile()` you'd need to "import" its name by inserting following declaration in `TilesWithData` for the overload to work properly:

```
using Tile::AddTile;
```